# Convert number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert a number to 0 (if the passed value is an integer) or 30 (if the passed value is float) using regex only.

Without regex it's pretty easy:

```
const someNumber = Number.isInteger(16.5) ? 0 : 30;
console.log(someNumber); // 30
```

But how to do this using regex?

Comment: `someNumber = /\./.test(16.5) * 30`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let someNumber = /\d+\./.test(16.5) ? 30 : 0;
let someNumber2 = /\d+\./.test(16) ? 30 : 0;
console.log(someNumber); 
console.log(someNumber2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only regex substitutions and type conversions:

```
n => Number(n.toString().replace(/^/, "30").replace(/(30)\d+(?:\.\d+)|3(0)\d+/, "$1$2"))
```